# How to convert an array into a string separated with comma after each item?

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, scilab

I am working in Scilab and I am having a little difficulty in displaying "," after each items of an array when converting it into string.
Suppose I have a variable with 3 values in it, like: `fruits = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Cherry']`
Now i am converting it into string using new = string(fruits)
and the output is `"Apple" "Banana" "Cherry"`
The desired output is `Apple, Banana, Cherry`
I am searching it's solution in various documentations but I couldn't understand

Comment: you can use [strcat](https://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.0/en_US/strcat.html): `strcat(fruits, ", ")`